# Convergence of matrices and entry-wise convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, normed-spaces

Let's consider the finite-dimensional vector space of $m \times n$ matrices with complex entries: $\mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$.

Consider the entry-wise $p$-norm $\|A\|_p=(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n |(A)_{ij}|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ defined on $\mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ with $p \ge 1$.

If there exists a sequence $\{A_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $m \times n$ matrices such that $A_k \to A$ with respect to $\|.\|_p$ (namely $\|A_k-A\|_p \to 0$ for $k \to +\infty$) then we obviously have that $|(A_k)_{ij}-(A)_{ij}| \to 0$ for every $i=1,\dots,m$ and $j=1,\dots,n$.

All the norms on a finite-dimensional vector space (like $\mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$) are equivalent. So if $A_k \to A$ with respect to a **generic norm** $\|.\|$ on $\mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ then it follows even that $A_k \to A$ with respect to the $p$-norm $\|.\|_p$, and then we have that $(A_k)_{ij} \to (A)_{ij}$.

**Then we can always conclude that if the sequence ${A_k}$ converges to $A$ with respect to a generic norm on $\mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ then we have also entry-wise convergence, namely the sequence of complex numbers $(A_k)_{ij}$ converges to $(A)_{ij}$ with $i=1,\dots,m$ and $j=1,\dots,n$. Am I right?** Thank you.

Comment: It looks correct to me. In any finite normed vector space, we have $A_k\to A$ w.r.t. any norm if and only if $(A_k)_{ij}\to A_{ij}$